# How to test the config of PHPMailer and find out the TSL version

Tags: phpmailer, tls1.2

Since i want to test the config of our PHPMailer i searched a whole day for a possibility to get something like a log with the config listed. I found [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#testing-ssl-outside-php) on the github page of PHPMailer where exactly that topic is described.

That is the part of the response that is interesting for me is:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
```

Unfortunately there is just described what command to use but not how:

> In order to eliminate PHP config or your code from encryption issues, you can use your local openssl installation to test the config directly using its built-in SMTP client, for example to test an explicit SMTP+STARTTLS config:
>
> `echo QUIT | openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587`

Because i have no experiences in something like unit testing and since there is nothing to find on google or on stackoverflow how to use that command i'm totally lost.

So please give me a hint. For example: should it be typed in a console on the server or should it be part of a test script or something else?

Comment: Why do you need PHPMailer for this?

Comment: I thought that this log shows the config of PHPMailer - does it not?

Comment: No, that output is from using the openssl command line client, so yes, you would type that in or run it as a script, though this is really for diagnosing particular circumstances rather than being part of unit tests because this is about deployment rather than code. PHPMailer is intended for sending email, not testing TLS configurations, so treat that separately. You may find that badssl.com is useful if you do want to run tests against known-bad TLS configs, and testssl.sh if you want to build local tests for remote TLS configs.

Comment: I know that PHPMailer is not for testing - we use it for sending Mails. But i thought the log would show the config of PHPMailer so that i could find out which tls version is supported from our PHPMailer. Anyway, the info and the two links you provided are what i need. If you convert your comment to an answer i will mark it as accepted...